# Не понимаю как работает воспроизведение звука видео Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, opencv, видео

Этот код воспроизводит видео со звуком:

```py
import cv2
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer


video_path = "video.mp4"


def play_video(video_path):
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    player = MediaPlayer(video_path)  # В этой строке создается переменная player которая нигде не используется
    while True:
        grabbed, frame = video.read()

        if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)

    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


play_video(video_path)
```

Обратите внимание на эту строку:

```py
player = MediaPlayer(video_path)
```

Здесь создается переменная `player` которая нигде не используется. Но если её убрать, то даже если оставить создание класса `MediaPlayer`, звук исчезнет.

Не могу понять почему так происходит(

Comment: Думаю, когда ссылка на объект находится в `player = `, тот объект не будет уничтожен сборщиком мусора